# Angular NgRx - Serialise auxiliary outlet, How to

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, ngrx

Say that I have the following URL:
http://localhost:4200/cats(sidePanel:muffins)

I can now use a custom route serialiser to get the url:

```
export class CustomRouteSerialiser implements RouterStateSerializer<NotImportantForStackOverflow> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let route = routerState.root;

    while (route.firstChild) {
        route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const { url } = routerState;

    return {
        url,
    };
  }
}
```

However I have no information regarding the axiliary route "sidePanel".
The only place I could find something was in:

```
routerState.root._urlSegment.children.sidePanel.segments
```

However, that's a non typed private property that I'm not supposed to use, but at the same time I can't find anything else.
I can't find anything regarding how to do this in a clean way.

So, how am I supposed to serialise auxiliary outlets in a clean way?

P.S.: Rather that going through `routerState.root._urlSegment.children.sidePanel.segments` and then mapping the array of Segments at that point I'd rather duplicate the information and store auxiliary routes manually somewhere else, dirty for dirty…

My current solution (I'm not happy about it):

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
const sidePanelOutlet  = (routerState.root as any)._urlSegment.children.sidePanel;
const auxiliaryOutlets = {
    sidePanel: sidePanelOutlet && sidePanelOutlet.segments[ 0 ].path,
};
```

Comment: Why are you not using params  instead of `()` ?

Comment: @Wandrille I don't get your question, please be more specific.

Comment: You have `(...)` in your url. This is a very strange design. Why are you not using params instead `myUrl?param1=foo&param2=bar`

Comment: @Wandrille that's the normal format for Angular auxiliary routes. It's Angular native. https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Comment: My bad, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's get some context.  In my instance, I have the possibility of multiple params in the primary outlet, along with the possibility of having an aux route with a parameter.
Example route: `/user/lgxAXtn...h2/home(modal:items/0fn...Z83)`

So, the solution I came up with is to create a collection of all the parameters.  To start, we need to break out the recursion so it's a little less confusing (for me, at least)

```js
traverse(root: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Params {
  // The object to be returned
  let params: Params = {};
  // The starting point
  let route = root;
  // Iterate til we hit the end
  while (route.firstChild) {
    route = route.firstChild;
    // Collect all params on the way there (if any)
    params = { ...params, ...route.params };
  }
  return params;
}
```

Now, this does a majority of the heavy lifting but we're not *quite* done yet.

```js
serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterReducer.State {
  // Since we want an object, we can just reduce the array.
  // root.children provides primary and modal outlets
  const params = routerState.root.children.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...this.traverse(curr) }),
    {}
  );
  // Full url
  const { url } = routerState;

  return { url, params };
}
```

The result?

```js
state: {
  url: '/user/lgxAXtn...h2/home(modal:items/0fn...Z83)',
  params: {
    userId: 'lgxAXtn...h2',
    itemId: '0fn...Z83'
  }
}
```

This is one of the more fun little solutions I've come up with, and it's been treating me well so far.  Let me know if you encounter any issues using this approach!

**Full serializer.ts for completeness**

```js
import {
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  Params,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import { RouterStateSerializer } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import * as RouterReducer from '../reducers/router.reducer';

export class ParamSerializer
  implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterReducer.State> {
  private traverse(root: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Params {
    // The object to be returned
    let params: Params = {};
    // The starting point
    let route = root;
    // Iterate til we hit the end
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
      // Collect all params on the way there (if any)
      params = { ...params, ...route.params };
    }
    return params;
  }

  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterReducer.State {
    // Since we want an object, we can just reduce the array.
    // root.children provides primary and modal outlets
    const params = routerState.root.children.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...this.traverse(curr) }),
      {}
    );
    // Full url
    const { url } = routerState;
    return { url, params };
  }
}
```

Now, in my instance I used it for params - getting segments is just a bit of a modification.  Something like `route.url` instead of route.params in the traverse function.